# Lua connectivity with SQL and accessing the result set

Tags: sql, syntax, lua, ssms, resultset

I am using lua with SQL and i am fairly new to lua. Now, I want to operate on the resultset that and I am not able to understand the exact syntax for that.

```
local M = conn:execute{live=true,sql="Select * from data "}
```

What is the syntax to access the resultset that I got through this statement?

Comment: Lua has no SQL support or even any common interface. It use external libraries and each library may provide its own interface. I never see this interface. At least you should find out what library you use and see doc for it.

Comment: If `M` is a table, try `for k,v in pairs(M) do print(k,v) end`.

Comment: And if `M` is not a table, but userdata, you can try to get the metatable: `for k, v in pairs(getmetatable(M)) do print(k, v) end`

Answer (score 1):

Unless you tell us what library are you using to connect, we are unable to help you fully. If it is LuaSQL connection, then you get a cursor object after the `execute` statement. From the [indirect docs of LuaSQL](http://keplerproject.github.io/luasql/doc/us/manual.html#cursor_object) on cursor objects, you see that you need to call the `fetch()` function to go through result-set.

```
local M = conn:execute{live=true,sql="Select * from data "}
for col1, col2, col3 in M:fetch() do
  print( col1, col2, col3 )
end
```